# Как скрыть скроллбар?

Tags: jquery, slider, javascript, html, css

Именно скрыть, а не вообще убрать как это делает overflow: hidden? Т.е. мне нужно, чтобы сам скроллинг при этом был доступен, так как (**только**) на событие "прокрутки колесиком мыши" подвешен слайдер.

Может как-то сделать его размеры 0х0, но только не **hidden**, это убивает слайдер.

Comment: Размеры слайдера фиксированные?

Comment: резиновый, но какое это имеет значение?

Comment: Если спросил, значит, имеет) Можно было бы его обернуть дивом меньшего размера с `overflow: hidden;`, тогда полоса прокрутки была бы вне поля видимости. А так вам видимо только убирать полосу совсем и отлавливать mouseWheelUp/Down.

Comment: mouseWheelUp/Down и так отлавливается, парадокс в том что на телефоне работает только тогда когда эта .., пардон, этот скроллбар виден, но вот некрасиво выглядит енто, на обычном компе еще как-то можно пережить, в том смысле что скрыть можно hidden'ом, а вот на телефоне "Зысь.."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Покопал в интернете - нашел такой скрипт ([**пример**](http://jsfiddle.net/3dMH2/)).
Идея очень интерестная. Может даже оставите "как есть". Если же убрать принципиально, то поправьте код под свои нужды.

Comment: там div'ом скроллбарчик сделан, я думаю выше коммент мой прочитаете и поймете в чем дело.

Answer (score 5):

Самый простой способ вот:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`scrollbar-width: none;` для мозилы

`::-webkit-scrollbar` для остальных